# Use a For Loop to alternate a set of ID's in a SQL query

Tags: sql, for-loop

I have a query calculating some gambling statistics for just one 'team_id' but I would like to calculate for all team_id's to create reports/graphs. I do know some python and wondering if a "for loop" would be most efficient for this.  I will be creating many queries similar to this one but need to add the team_id in the Select portion(next to ATS_Status) of the query and include every team.  Any suggestions would be great.

```
 select ATS_Status, round((cast(count(*) as float) /75*100),2) as ATS_Percentage 
      from (select 
     (case  when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) < cast(spread2 as float) then 'Covered'
            when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) = cast(spread2 as float) then 'Push'
            else 'Loss' end) as ATS_Status
     from nba_games_all g1
     left outer join nba_games_all g2 on g1.game_id = g2.game_id
     and g1.team_id =g2.a_team_id
     left join nba_teams_all t on t.team_id=g1.a_team_id
     left join nba_betting_spread bs on g1.game_id = bs.game_id
     and book_name = 'Bovada'
     left join nba_betting_money_line ml on g1.game_id = ml.game_id
     and ml.book_name = 'Bovada'
     where g1.team_id = '1610612759' 
     and g1.season_year = '2017' 
     and g1.season_type = 'Regular Season'
     and g1.game_date >= Convert(datetime, '2017-11-02'))a
     group by ATS_Status
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `team_id` in the `group by` and remove the particular condition `g1.team_id = '1610612759'`  as follows:

```
select ATS_Status, team_id, round((cast(count(*) as float) /75*100),2) as ATS_Percentage 
      from (select 
     (case  when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) < cast(spread2 as float) then 'Covered'
            when cast(g2.pts as float)-cast(g1.pts as float) = cast(spread2 as float) then 'Push'
            else 'Loss' end) as ATS_Status, g1.team_id
     from nba_games_all g1
     left outer join nba_games_all g2 on g1.game_id = g2.game_id
     and g1.team_id =g2.a_team_id
     left join nba_teams_all t on t.team_id=g1.a_team_id
     left join nba_betting_spread bs on g1.game_id = bs.game_id
     and book_name = 'Bovada'
     left join nba_betting_money_line ml on g1.game_id = ml.game_id
     and ml.book_name = 'Bovada'
     where --g1.team_id = '1610612759' 
     g1.season_year = '2017' 
     and g1.season_type = 'Regular Season'
     and g1.game_date >= Convert(datetime, '2017-11-02'))a
     group by ATS_Status, team_id
```

Comment: thank you, weird but when i copy and paste your edits  and code it works but when I change it myself I get error message "The multi-part identifier "g1.team_id" could not be bound." team_id is in 3 different tables, do you know which one it is pulling it from when i paste your code or why I would be getting that error?

Comment: Have you given correct alias name before column name?

Comment: yes I was using 'g1.team_id' and its not liking it, I pasted your code with just' team_id' and no issue.  I really  want to group by 'abbreviation' which is from 'nba_teams_all' but its not liking that either

Comment: Ok. In outer query, you just have to use team_id. Without alias and in subquery we have to use it with alias.